# How to delete an object property in an expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If it was as part of a **code block**, I could do this:

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
delete obj.a;
console.log(obj);
```

Or this:

```js
const {a, ...rest} = {a: 1, b: 2};
console.log(rest);
```

Is there a way to do this in an **expression**? Like this (pseudocode!):

```js
console.log(Object.removeProperty({a: 1, b: 2}, 'a'));
```

---

### Context / use case

I am aware of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object) but the answers always seem to use *statements*, not *expressions*.

I want expressions as I'm in a middle of mapping one object to another, like this:

```js
function mapSomethingToSomethingElse(obj) {
  return {
    prop1: obj.prop1,
    prop2: obj.prop2,
    prop3: {
      ...Object.removeProperty(obj.prop3, 'a') // <- HERE
      abc: def,
    },
    // ...
  }
}
```

I can hide the statements into a helper function, that's always an option, but in my specific case, I'd be happy enough with in-line expression if one can be written in JavaScript.

Comment: `delete obj.a` is already an expression. You can use `const result = (delete obj.a, obj);` if you really need the `result` alias. Otherwise just use `delete obj.a` and keep `obj` since it’s the same object, anyway.

Comment: What would the return value be?

Comment: Why do you want to remove a property with a function? What's wrong in using `delete`? Are you considering the trivial solution of just defining a custom function?

Comment: Are you looking for object to be immutable? (maybe look into a library such as immutable.js)

Comment: To be clear, `delete` is an *operator* in the expression grammar.

Comment: @SethMcClaine No, this question is about how to delete object properties in an expression context, not how to make objects immutable (which you can already do by `Object.freeze` without the library).

Comment: create your own delete function which returns the objects

Comment: Thanks all, I've updated the OP to provide a little bit more context but I'd rather focus on the technicality of it as I'd use such construct in other places as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) for an object:

> Deleting a property from an object:
>   There isn't any method in an Object itself to delete its own properties (e.g. like Map.prototype.delete()). To do so one has to use the delete operator.

Comment: But there is [`Reflect.deleteProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/deleteProperty).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Oh cool, you should post that as an answer. Didn't know that existed.